# Generate query string from string[]

Tags: c#, string, http

In C# I'm using `UriBuilder` to build a GET request. Works fine except for where the query string needs to represent a string array using square brackets notation. How do I do that?

The data to form the query is in the form: `string[] obs_section`

The query string needs to look like (e.g.): `'obs_section':['a','b','c']`

I tried:

```
Query["obs_section"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obs_section)
```

but that gives the wrong format.

Here is what a working example query in Python looks like. I'm trying to replicate in C#:

```
entry = requests.get("https://filtergraph.com/aavso/api/v1/targets",auth=(userid,password),params={'obs_section':['a','b','c']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string.Join()` to join an array and make a string:

```
string QS = $"'obs_section':[{string.Join(",",obs_section.Select(x => $"'{x}'"))}]";
```

Here is a [**Live Demo**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ES1nsU) of how it works.